# Android: onBackPressed() destroy all memory?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, back

I want, when I press the back button on one of my activities, to go back to the previous activity but before that I need to delete all bitmaps and other resources in memory first otherwise I get an outofmemory error.

I tried:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   bitmap.recycle();
   System.gc();
   Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
   this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But still have the outofmemory error with that.

Comment: Offtopic: why do you start an new Activity on backpressed, instead of just letting this one close. Your previous one will get automatically started.

Comment: Don't create intent and the new activity but, call `super.onBackPressed` in place of it. Guess you need to learn the power of `onResume` and `onPause`

Comment: When I press back button it goes to my previous activity but the activity is how it looks like in the end, not in the begining

Comment: Could you develop please pKs

Comment: The previous activity will be automatically be resumed whenever the user press the back button. Just delete this whole code, and do clean-up on the onStop or onPause

Comment: If I don't override the onBackPressed method and clean my last activity with "onStop" I still have memory error

Answer (score 0):

Even if you call gc() there are still references to the objects in your activity which can't be collected. If the memory issue is related to some objects declared in your activity try changing their reference to null and than calling gc(). If you mantain some large cache try using WeakReference. Of course, performance will be degraded but you might not crash

The behaviour you are getting looks more like a flaw in design. The app uses too much memory and even if it will work on the device where you are currently testing might have issues on others. System.gc() should generally be called only by the OS as nothing is guaranteed when you do it.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. But what should I do to clean everything at the start at every new activity?

Comment: You can't clean everything. One of the reason is because that's not how Java is supposed to work. It doesn't provide the support from C/C++ regarding memory allocations deallocations. A second reason for not being able to deallocate everything is because some objects are being referenced by the system. Those should be deallocated when onDestroy() is called but that's out of your control. Try to understand why you run out of memory. The tools in Eclipse can provide good information about the memory allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't override `onBackPressed()`

override `onStop()`

```
@Override    
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    bitmap.recycle(); //PUT THE ACTUAL BITMAP THAT YOU WANT TO RECYCLE HERE !!!!!!!
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  What if the onStop is called by the system because it needs to kill the app?

Comment: + I don't want to start the previous Activity when my last activity stops but when I press the back button

Comment: @morg when you press the back button onStop() gets called, if you want to have both activities running I agree this is not the way to go

Comment: No I don't want both activities running. If I clean the bitmpas of the previous activity on its "onstop", when I come back to it pressing the back button, the screen is white. If I don't clean the bitmpas I have my previous activity in the end of the animation and not in the begining

Answer (score 0):

call this on the press of back button :-

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
     Log.d(TAG,"in unbindDrawables");
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        view.setBackgroundResource(0);
        Log.d(TAG,"removed views");
        //finish();   

        }
 }
```

Comment: Be careful with `((ViewGroup)view).removeAllViews()` - it may throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, for example, if you have adapter views.

Comment: When I do that in the previous activity (in onStop()) and the second activity on (onBackPressed()) I go back to the begining at the activity (what I wanted) but if I touch the screen (it launches an animation), I still have the memory error

Comment: It seems that even when I unbind the bitmpas there are still in the memory ! I have memory error when I unbind in all the activities

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that on the previous Activity

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
 unbidDrawables and recycle bitmaps
}

@Override
public void onRestart(){
    onCreate(new Bundle());
}
```

It's like a makeshift job but it works !